# where to define header for a new protocol in linux kernel code

Tags: header, network-programming, kernel

In the previous linux kernels, there used to be a union of different headers in the sk_buff structure. This was phased out as this was thought to be redundant (my speculation, correct me if I'm wrong)
http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_redundancy.html

Now I'd like to add a new transport protocol with it's own header. I need a function like udp_hdr

`static inline struct udphdr *udp_hdr(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    return (struct udphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
}`

so I can easily access the header from sk_buff.

Will just writing a similar function like above do the trick or do I need to do something more?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before.

Quick answer:Yes, you should implement helper functions like that.
I suggest you look at the code in kernel source net/ipv4/udp.c, implement the relevant functions that you need for your protocol(eg.udp_rcv(), udp_send_skb(), ...).

Also you should define a protocol id that is not conflict with any existing transport protocol ids.And register your new protocol to the inet.
sample code in net/ipv4/af_inet.c
inet_add_protocol(&udp_protocol, IPPROTO_UDP);

By registering the protocol, IP layer can figure out which transport layer receive handler(eg.udp_rcv in UDP case) to call with protocol id in IP header.
Sample code in net/ipv4/ip_input.c ip_local_deliver_finish()

```
205                 ipprot = rcu_dereference(inet_protos[protocol]);
206                 if (ipprot) {
207                         int ret;
208 
                        ... ...
216                         ret = ipprot->handler(skb);
```